# what is gem support Prolific Payment Gateway?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment-gateway, payment

In authorize.net I used active merchant gem but activemerchant not support Prolific Payment Gateway. please suggest me a gem or way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any gem, but you can always implement their API yourself. It sounds harder than it really is.